# Custom drawing MT.D borders

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I've been playing around with MT.D a bit and love the simplicity of it all.

I have now been working on a completely owner drawn cell using a UIView to do all the drawing and an Element that allows me to use it with MT.D.

Now the only thing I seem to be missing is the ability to control how borders are drawn (or not drawn). If I set the mode to Grouped then I get the indented and rounded borders and Plain I get the simple horizontal border.

But lets say I want to use an image or thicker border for my borders, how do I go about customising this?